# Как в столбиковой диаграмме в matplotlib оставить по оси х только целые числа?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Мой код:

```
def production_bars(demand1, setup_cost1, holding_cost1):
    data = s(demand1, setup_cost1, holding_cost1)

    f = plt.figure()
    production_level = get_order_quantities(data) #list_of_prod
    periods = [x + 1 for x in range(len(demand1))]
    plt.bar(periods, production_level, color='c', align='center')

    plt.title('Dynamic lot-size problem chart\nProduction level by period')
    plt.ylabel('Units')
    plt.xlabel('Periods')
    plt.grid(True)

    #return f
    #plt.show()

    f.savefig("bar.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

На выходе получается (например):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне оставить по оси х тольḱо целые числа (1,2,3,4... без 0,5; 1,5 и т.д.)? И как я могу добавить значения самих столбиков (на них или над ними) непосредственно на диаграмме?

Упрощенная версия:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
f = plt.figure()
production_level = [54, 83, 21, 3] #list_of_prod
periods = [x+1 for x in range(len(production_level))] #list_of_order

plt.bar(periods, production_level, color='orange')

plt.title('Dynamic lot-size problem chart')
plt.ylabel('Units')
plt.xlabel('Periods')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
f.savefig("bar.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Вы можете привести пример входных данных?

Comment: @MaxU Hапример: x = [54, 83, 21, 3] и y = [x + 1 for x in range(len(x))]

Comment: [Вот пример функции, кот. автоматически делает надписи над столбцами](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43443823/5741205)

Answer (score 1):

`xtics` и `ytics` в помощь.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html#matplotlib-pyplot-xticks

```py
plt.xticks(periods)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/758575)